# How to properly increment a specific variable in aspnet?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Im trying to increment this specific element in ASPnet. A user selects a specific item in the dropdown box, and it increases the quantity as the user selects.

```
If DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0
        intDonutqty += 1
        txtDonut.Text = intDonutqty

    End If
```

Everything else works fine, but for some reason it just stays at 1 without incrementing.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in the page are local to the instance of the `Page` class, and the instance is only used to handle one request. When you make a postback and the next request comes for the page, a new instance of the Page class is created, so you will get a brand new variable which starts out at zero.

To keep the value between requests, you either have to store it in a session variable, in the ViewState, in a cookie, or a hidden field in the form.

Comment: Nevermind, I will figure it out. Thank you very much for your response.